# Are the multi-valued Eudoxus reals constructively equivalent to the Dedekind reals?

Tags: constructive-mathematics

Without LEM or the axiom of choice, we can prove that the [Eudoxus reals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eudoxus+real+number) are equivalent to the Cauchy reals but can't prove either of those equivalent to the Dedekind reals.

However, we can prove that the [*multi-valued* Cauchy reals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+real+number#generalisations) are equivalent to the Dedekind reals. My question is if we can say the same about a kind of multi-valued Eudoxus real?

In particular, a multi-valued Eudoxus real will be represented by a set $R \subseteq \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ (thought of as a relation) such that $\forall x \in \mathbb Z. \exists a \in \mathbb Z. xRa$ and the set $\{a + b - c: \exists x, y \in \mathbb Z. xRa \land yRb \land (x+y)Rc\}$ is bounded. Relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ represent the same multi-valued Eudoxus real when the set $\{a - b : \exists x, y \in \mathbb Z. xR_1a \land yR_2b\}$ is bounded.

We turn this into an ordered field in the same way as we do the (single-valued) Eudoxus reals. The Eudoxus reals are subfield of the multi-valued Eudoxus reals, and they are equal if we assume the axiom of countable choice.

We can embed a multi-valued Eudoxus real $e$ into the Dedekind reals via the Dedekind cut $(\{p \in \mathbb Q: p < e\}, \{q \in \mathbb Q: e < q\})$, as usual. My question: **is this embedding surjective?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

In particular, for any real number $r$, we can construct a total relation $R$ representing it such that $B = \{a + b - c: \exists x, y \in \mathbb Z. xRa \land yRb \land (x+y)Rc\} \subseteq \{-1, 0,1\}$.

In classical mathematics, we usually define $xRa$ as $a = \lfloor xr \rfloor$, which is equivalent to $a \in [xr, xr+1)$. The floor function doesn't exist constructively. So instead we define $xRa$ as $$a \in (xr - \frac 23, xr + \frac 23)$$

This is total because we can find a rational $p \in (xr - \frac 16, xr + \frac 16)$ (because $\mathbb Q$ is dense) and then an integer $a \in [p - \frac 12, p + \frac 12]$. Thus $|a - xr| < \frac 23$ by the triangle inequality.

Note that $xRa$ is equivalent to $\exists \delta \in (-\frac 23, \frac 23). a = xr + \delta$. Now we find a bound on $B$.

$$a + b - c = (xr + \delta_1) + (yr + \delta_2) - ((x+y)r + \delta_3) \text{ for some $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ and $\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3 \in (-\frac 23, \frac 23)$}$$
$$a + b - c = \delta_1 + \delta_2 + (-\delta_3)$$
$$|a + b - c| = |\delta_1 + \delta_2 + (-\delta_3)|$$
$$\le |\delta_1| + |\delta_2| + |\delta_3|$$
$$< \frac 23 + \frac 23 + \frac 23$$
$$= 2$$

Thus $a + b - c \in (-2,2)$. We already know that $a + b - c \in \mathbb Z$, and thus $$a + b -c \in \mathbb Z \cap (-2,2) = \{-1, 0, 1\}$$
$\square$